# Keyboard is hiding part of a Dialog on Android 7 OS(Xamarin.Android)

Tags: xamarin.android, dialog

I have the following two EditTexts:

[image: EditText]

When I click on either of the two, it appears a Dialog with a list of products and a filter above them in this way:

[image: Dialog's appearing]

The problem is that when I tap on the filter, the keyboard is hiding part of the products. My question is how to make the Dialog adjust to the keyboard so all its content can be seen. I tried with:

```
filterListDialog.Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize);
```

But it's only working on Android 4 OS and not on Android 7 OS, and I'd like it to work on both operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

Do you add the `windowSoftInputMode` property to `adjustNothing` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` of the activities that use the dialog fragment like following code.

```
 <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
 <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
        android:name=".MainActivity" />
 </application>
```

Before show the CustomDialog ,you should set the `customDialog.Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize);`

```
 CustomDialog customDialog = new CustomDialog(this);
 customDialog.Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize);
 customDialog.Show();
```

There is running GIF.

[image]

The following is a demo.
https://github.com/851265601/CustomDialog-

Comment: Your demo is working but is there a way to make the keyboard appear only if I've clicked on the input field in the dialog, not when I click on the EditText? By the way, not adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` in your demo also worked.

Comment: The way to do that would be to replace the EditText in your page layout with a TextView and add a ClickListener to it that triggers the dialog, which contains an EditText for the filter input. Then when a selection has been made, populate the TextView as well as dismissing the dialog,

Comment: @Bonucci ,yes,you can delete the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" in the AndroidManifest.xml`, it will still work. But do not delete `customDialog.Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize);`.If you want to click on the input field in the dialog, then make the keyborad appear. Dave's comment that you could try it.

Comment: Leon Lu - MSFT I moved the custom dialog of my application into the demo you send me and and it worked correctly. Do you know what may be the cause it not to work in my application?

Comment: Did you add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the parent layout of custom dialog

Comment: Yes, and I also tried making parent layout to be `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` in addition to `LinearLayout`